# How to join 2 tables with alias and condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Table1:  Contractors

```
Contractor_No; -- PK
Contractor;
```

Table2:  Contracts

```
Contract_No;   -- PK
ProjDesc;
Contractor_No; -- FK
```

How to retrieve data by joining these 2 table with Contractor (from Table1), Contract_No, ProjDesc from (Table2)?

My SQL statment:

```
select a.Contractor, b.ProjDesc
from Contractors a, Contracts b
join Contractor a on a.Contractor_No = b.Contractor_No and b.Contract_No='1234';
```

Answer (score 2):

You have some syntax errors:

```
SELECT a.Contractor
     , b.ProjDesc
FROM Contractors a 
JOIN Contracts b ON a.Contractor_No = b.Contractor_No 
                AND b.Contract_No = '1234'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.Contractor,
       b.ProjDesc
from   Constractors a
       inner join contracts b on
        a.contractor_no = b.contractor_no
where  b.contract_no = '1234'
```

Comment: Should be `b.Contract_No` in the last line instead of `b.Contractor_No`. Other than that, I like this answer better because it moves the line that's specific to one table out of the `JOIN` and into the `WHERE`.

Comment: Thanks @Adam V, I modified the answer.